Unable to generate new virtualenv from Python Interpreter in Pycharm
I'm currently on Windows and want to create a virtualenv for a new project in Pycharm. When I open an already created project folder and try to add a new Python interpreter, it doesn't let me press okay to create the venv folder.

My python.exe locations are:
C:\Users\username>where python
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\anacondapro\python.exe
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

There is also another location detected in the Interpreter:

It still doesn't let me create one from either that one nor the anacondapro one.
But if I create a new project from Pycharm, it will let me create a new virtual environment from either python.exe path.

I'm not quite sure why, but would like to get this resolved.

Does it become enabled if you select a different location for the new venv? The directory you choose may already have something in?

No, just the .idea folder which I delete (but comes back). I tried changing location and same issue. I tried on another windows laptop (with similar installation) and it also does the same. It doesn't let me generate a new one from an already created folder, only if I create a brand new project.
